# Failed Binder Transaction after starting an activity

Tags: android

I have one activity that contains several fragments, which in turn contain much data (maps and lists). On particular tap, I need to launch a new activity that doesn't need that data, so I don't have to pass it via an intent or somehow else. Nevertheless, after a new activity has started and showed its content, I get !! Failed Binder Transaction !! in LogCat and a huge lag  before the screen responds to touches.

I tried to assign null to all big variables, to clear maps and lists before starting the new activity, nothing helps.

My guess is that much of data that exceeds binder transaction limit of 1 mb is passing to the new activity via context, when i'm trying

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, MySecondActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

but I'm clearing all big data before that call, can you explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with myList.removeAll(myList). After clearing data that way the new activity starts without lags and no !! Failed Binder Transaction !! in LogCat.

See [What is the difference between ArrayList.clear() and ArrayList.removeAll()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032070/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-clear-and-arraylist-removeall)