# What are ArrayList's most performance friendly methods?

Tags: java

I need to know which of the following `ArrayList` methods is the most performance friendly:

```
arrayList.add(index,Object)
arrayList.clear()
```

I'm in a situation where I have to choose to either add 1 element to the first position of a non empty arraylist or to just clear the whole arrayList. What would you choose?

Comment: what exactly you want elaborate more on it

Comment: They're really not alternatives to each other, so the comparison is meaningless...

Comment: The last 2 may be to some extent comparable but not the 1st

Comment: http://java-performance.info/arraylist-performance/

Comment: Actually using Big-Oh these are _all_ comparable.

Comment: If you are adding an item to a specific index, removing from a specific index, or removing , they have a runtime of O(1). Think about it logically; you are giving it the **EXACT** location that it needs to go to in the first 2 cases. clear() would simply remove everything from the list, without discriminating. IMO this is an easily answerable question with small amount of research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Big-Oh notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), we can generalise the time complexity of methods within the `ArrayList` class.

For an `ArrayList<>` the following operations can be defined as follows:

- `get()` has a time complexity of `O(1)`
- `add()`, `clear()` and `remove()` all have a time complexity of `O(n)`
- `removeAll()` has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`

From this, it can be seen that `get()` has the least time complexity and doesn't depend on the size of the list to how it performs. You should also note `add()`, `clear()` and `remove()` all run in linear time - which isn't as efficient but is not generally considered bad for performance.

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run
>   in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time,
>   that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other
>   operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor
>   is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

### Why Big-Oh? ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418021/717778))

> Big O notation is a way of describing how quickly an algorithm will
>   run given an arbitrary number of input parameters, which we'll call
>   `n`. It is useful in computer science because different machines
>   operate at different speeds, and simply saying that an algorithm takes
>   5 seconds doesn't tell you much because while you may be running a
>   system with a 4.5 Ghz multi-core processor, I may be running a 15 year
>   old, 800 Mhz system, which could take longer regardless of the
>   algorithm.
>
> So instead of specifying how fast an algorithm runs in terms of
>   *time*, we say how fast it runs in terms of number of *input parameters*, or `n`.
>
> By describing algorithms in this way, we are able to compare the
>   speeds of algorithms without having to take into account the speed of
>   the computer itself.

Sources: [Big-Oh cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7032144/717778)

Comment: check my edited question. Which of those actions is more efficient? I'm mostly interested about add(i, object) vs clear()

Comment: Just a few clarifications. You say that add() and clear() have the same complexity? So if you were to choose between add(1,Object) which adds a new object to position 0 and clear() which just clears everything. Which one would be the fastest?

Comment: Please describe what you actually want to do.  Those two methods do completely different things; why are you choosing between them?

Comment: @ThanosF You asked about efficiency, but you seem to be confused by what that actually means. How fast something executes in practice depends on a whole variety of factors, if you want to see which is faster on your machine - create a test program and run it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain a bit better why measuring algorithms by time is flawed

Comment: thank you @EdGeorge that makes it clearer to my head. This is about an android phone so I may run some tests

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm in a situation where I have to choose to either add 1 element to the first position of a non empty arraylist or to just clear the whole arrayList. Don't ask how I got to that situation. long story. What would you choose?

Comment: I would choose to hear the long story, but frankly I would expect no measurable difference in performance.

Comment: The above comment is correct, you should see an extremely negligible difference in performance. For 'quicker' insertion and deletion, you could use a linked-list (`O(1)`) but at the cost of running at linear time when it comes to access elements of the list (`O(n)`)

Answer (score 1):

It depends, how may items are there in the ArrayList. The worst case scenarion will be whne there a lot of items and the array list should be extended/shrinked. In this case the clear() method is the fastest. The other 2 involve System.arrayCopy the old array into new one.

Comment: So in that situation is it faster to use clear() instead of add(i,Object?)

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm wondering how can you use clear instead of add?

Comment: Well it's a long story. I'm in a situation where I have to choose to either add 1 element to the first position of a non empty arraylist or to just clear the whole arrayList. The guys above said that there is no difference on performance between those 2 actions since they both have O(n) complexity

Comment: They are right, so am I :). O(n) means linear complexity., which both methods have. The difference `clear` has 1*n and `add` has 2*n if the underlying byte array has to be extended.