# Should I use ArrayList.clear() or create a new list?

Tags: java

So, sort of in continuation of this post: [What is the difference between ArrayList.clear() and ArrayList.removeAll()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032070/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-clear-and-arraylist-removeall)... Are there certain situations where it is actually better to use `removeAll()` instead of `clear()`?

---

Also, to add onto this question, if I know I'm clearing all the contents of an `ArrayList`, would it be ok to set it to a new `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<String>();

myList.add("a");
myList.add("b");

// instead of using:  myList.clear();
myList = new ArrayList<String>()
```

If the above is ok to do, again, why use `clear()` vs setting to a new `ArrayList`? Creating a new, empty `ArrayList` is faster than *O*(*n*).

Comment: Yes, if you need to `remove` well, `all` the elements in _another_ `List` from the current one. `clear` and `removeAll` are completely different methods and have completely different use cases. You almost **never** want to assign a `new ArrayList` rather than call `clear` - for example, how do you even know that the `List` you have is an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why use `clear()` instead of creating a new `ArrayList`? Several reasons:

- You might not be allowed to reassign a reference field that points to an ArrayList, so you can clear an existing list but not put a new one in its place. For example:

  ```
  class MyData {
      // Can clear() but not reassign
      final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ```
- The variable might be declared as `List`. The actual type could be `LinkedList` and you want to preserve it instead of replacing the implementation with an `ArrayList`.
- It's not necessarily true that `clear()` is *O*(*n*) time. One implementation strategy is to nullify all the existing elements in the backing array in *O*(*n*) time. But another equally valid implementation is to throw away that internal array and replace it with a new one, preferably a short array for *O*(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ArrayList.removeAll()`.
But there is an `ArrayList.removeAll(Collection)`.

The method `clear()` should be faster than `removeAll(Collection)` because removeAll(Collection) does some comparisions to decide if an object should be removed from the list.  The `clear()` method simply removes everything without thinking.

Comment: These methods are completely _different_, and the question you are answering is already answered in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032070/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-clear-and-arraylist-removeall). You are [comparing apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges) and not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove a specific collection from your list but you don't want to remove everything, you will use remove all with the collection that you want to remove.