# Best practice for removing all items from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a java ArrayList and need to remove all the items from it, then fill it up again, but this time with a different group of items.

What is the best-practice way to remove all the items in an ArrayList, because I think there are a few and I don't know which is best:

```
my_array_list.removeAll(my_array_list);    //this seems a bit strange to be the norm?

for (String aString : my_array_list) {    //is it really needed to use a for loop just to remove all the elements?
    my_array_list.remove(aString);
}

for (int i = 0; i < my_array_list.size(); i++) {    //for loop again, but using indexes instead of object to remove everything
    my_array_list.remove(i);
}
```

Thanks so much for you answers.

Comment: You should consider throwing away the old list and creating a fresh one.

Comment: I know it's not great, but I do use the list under the original name later on (although at that later point I need all of it's items to (potentially) be different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this article mention: [What is the difference between ArrayList.clear() and ArrayList.removeAll()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032070/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-clear-and-arraylist-removeall)
**arrayList.clear()** is really good

Comment: @Note: `clear()` is `O(n)` however `removeAll(everything)` is `O(N^2)`

Comment: And the other two examples don't work. Second example will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and third example will only remove half the elements.

Comment: Just checking, am I right in saying that the 3rd example will only remove half the elements because it is in a for loop that is removing elements from what dictates how many iterations the for loop has left?

Answer (score 4):

To remove all elements from an `ArrayList`,
you don't need a loop, use the [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()) method:

```
my_array_list.clear();
```